# Icon color not changed on press in react native

Tags: react-native

This is my code

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react'

import {
Body,
Text,
View
} from 'native-base'
import {
Icon
} from 'react-native-elements'

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        iconColour: "red"
      }
  }

   func() {
    console.warn("changed")
    this.setState({
        iconColor: "blue"
    })
  }

 render() {
    return (
        <View>
    <Text> textInComponent </Text>
    <Icon name='map' color={this.state.iconColour} onPress= 
       {()=>this.func()}/>
    </View>
       )
     } 
 }
```

i want to change the color of icon when pressed

but the color does not update

the function works and state changed but the view is not updated

i think i missed a simple thing

i searched but i can't find similar situation

i think a command should run to render the view with new properties

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

Just change `iconColor: "blue"` to `iconColour: "blue"`:))